# I'm having a problem while trying to switch screens with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

to be specific almost everything works, its just that when I try to change window using app.root.current: * Name of page * nothing happens, the program doesn't crash or show any warnings it just acts as if I've never written that line at all.

I tried removing the 'if' on line 41 in the kivy file but it made no difference.

**python code:**

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import validity
from validity import Validity


""" class for the login window """

class LoginWindow(Screen, FloatLayout, Widget):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_input(self):
        valid_email = False
        valid_password = False

        """ uses custom made funcition to check email and password """

        if validity.Validity.checkMail(self.email.text):
            print("Valid Email")
            valid_email = True
        else:
            print("Invalid Email")

        if validity.Validity.checkPassword(self.password.text):
            print("Valid Password")
            valid_password = True
        else:
            print("Invalid Password")

            """ return True or False as str"""
        return str(valid_email and valid_password)


class MainWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager, FloatLayout):
    pass

class LoginInfoPage(Screen, FloatLayout):
    pass

build = Builder.load_file("build.kv")

class runApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return build

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runApp().run()
```

**kivy file:**

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:
    LoginInfoPage:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login_page"

    email: email_id
    password: password_id

    Label: 
        text: "Email: "
        pos_hint: {"x": 0 , "top": 1}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1

    TextInput:
        id: email_id
        multiline:False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 1}
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

    Label:
        text: "Password: "
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.9}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1


    TextInput:
        id: password_id
        multiline:False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.9}
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

    Button:
        text: "Login"
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 1}
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        on_release: 
            app.root.current: "main_page" if  root.check_input() == 'True' else "login_page"

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main_page"

    Button:
        text: "Welcome to the main window!" 
        on_release:
            app.root.current: "login_page"

<LoginInfoPage>:
    name: "login_info_page"
```

**thank you to anyone who's trying to help**

Comment: You are creating new object of WindowManager instead of describing your class, try to write it like this `<WindowManager>:` in kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
    on_release: 
        app.root.current = "main_page" if  root.check_input() else "login_page"
```

May need to change `check_input()` to return

```
        """ return True or False """
    return valid_email and valid_password
```

Comment: ill give it a try

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED FINALY